# If graph isomorphism is in P, is then P = NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np, graph-isomorphism

I think that, since graph isomorphism is not known to be $\textbf{NP}$-complete, we can not reduce all problems in $\textbf{NP}$ to it, and therefore the implication does not hold.

Additionally, [in the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553577/how-do-we-know-np-complete-problems-are-the-hardest-in-np) it is stated, that a proof that graph isomorphism is not $\textbf{NP}$-complete would prove $\textbf{P} \neq \textbf{NP}$. Why?

Comment: If P=NP then every nontrivial problem in NP is NP-complete.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**We don't know.**

We do know that $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$ implies graph isomorphism is in $\textbf{P}$, but the other implication has not been proven (to the best of my knowledge). It is suspected graph isomorphism is $\textbf{NP}$-intermediate (i.e., it is in $\textbf{NP} \setminus \textbf{P}$ and not $\textbf{NP}$-complete). [This question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-evidence-is-there-that-graph-isomorphism-is-not-in-p) as well as [this other one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29266/evidence-that-graph-isomorphism-problem-is-not-np-complete) list evidences supporting said suspicions.

---

Regarding your second question: If $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$, then any (nontrivial) problem in $\textbf{NP}$ is trivially $\textbf{NP}$-complete because any (nontrivial) problem in $\textbf{P}$ is $\textbf{P}$-complete (and we have assumed $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$). Hence, by contraposition, if the conclusion of this implication is false (i.e., there is a problem in $\textbf{NP}$ which is not $\textbf{NP}$-complete), then the premise (i.e., $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$) must also be false.